# Where is the mysterious EntityFramework database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my main project, I have configured a connection string to my database like this:

```
<add name="DefaultStoreConnection" "provider....">
```

In my infrastructure project, I have a database context with a default constructor that passes the connection name to the base class:

```
public DatabaseContext() : base("DefaultStoreConnection") {}
```

As soon as my application starts, EF generates a 'store.sdf' (SQLCe database) in the application output folder (\bin).

Now, I wanted to reset all migrations and start with a plain database. I deleted the 'store.sdf' in the \bin directory, deleted all migration files and then called in the Package Manager Console:

```
Enable-Migrations -Force -ProjectName "MyInfrastructureProject" -StartUpProjectName "MyMainProject".
```

This worked fine, a new migrations configuration class was generated. Then I ran:

```
Add-Migration Initial -ProjectName....
```

And then the following line appears:

```
A previous migration called 'Initial' was already applied to the target database
```

Where? Where does this migration has been applied to? Where can I reset this 'migration'?

Comment: If you add -Verbose, does it give you any additional information about what DB it is attempting to connect to?

Answer (score 0):

It should be in a folder containing all the migrations, but it's possible that it's deleted after it has been applied to database. You can see list of applied migrations in `__MigrationHistory` table of your target database. If you wish to rescaffold the database, empty the `__MigrationHistory` table.

Comment: How can I see my __MigrationHistory when I deleted my database as I stated in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I run to the same problem as you. After a day of google search without a single useful help, i figured it out myself that this is Visual Studio bug where your solution have more than one Mvc projects. The add-migration will check on the older Mvc project to create migration file for your current project (that is why i call it BUG).

**To avoid this, you should only use one Mvc project per solution.**

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the `app_data` folder of your project.

Comment: App_Data folders usually exist only in web projects. I never mentioned I'm using EF in a ASPX/MVC project.